# Entity Framework Core : how to add conditional where clause from input filter parameter?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am not sure if this is possible, but I have a linq to sql statement that takes in input filter parameter which could be null or missing a value like so

```
public List<MyViewModel> GetRecords(SearchDto? filter)
{
    List<MyViewModel> results = 
        this.dbContext.MyTable
            Where(s => s.IsActive == 'Y' &&
                       filter != null && !stringIsNullOrEmpty(s.deptId) && s.deptId == filter.deptId)
                 ToList();
}
```

When I add the conditional filter in the Where clause, my result is 0 count when the filter is null or empty.

I prefer not to do the old fashion way which is after the linq is call, add many lines of code like the following

```
if (!string.IsNullEmpty(filter.deptId)
{
     results = result.Where(s => s.deptId == filter.deptId);
}
```

I would like to add the conditional Where filter in the linq statement instead of old fashion C# code.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: "I prefer not to do the old fashion way which..." - any particular reasons why it is not suitable for you?

Comment: As you see, "the old fashioned way" is perfectly clear. Your preferred way makes you choke in the predicate logic even when adding one predicate.

Comment: Also, EF core is able of removing predicates from the translated query when they're not useful, but other LINQ implementations will translate everything into SQL yielding a very convoluted SQL query that may perform significantly worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly represent conditionally added filtering like in the "old fashion way" you should use something like this:

```
.Where(s.IsActive == 'Y' 
    && (filter == null 
        || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.deptId) ||  s.deptId == filter.deptId))`
```

So the "optional" condition evaluates to `true` for your AND clause when `filter` is null or empty.